# Writing an algorithm for a method that would take a graph in matrix form as a parameter

Tags: algorithm

I am new at algorithm. I am a bit confused about writing an algorithm.

Well, I have to write an algorithm for a method that would take a graph in matrix form as a parameter?

Also, I need to create a transpose graph in matrix format. I think I can possibly do that if I am able to solve my first problem (writing an algorithm for a method that take a graph in a matrix form as a parameter ).

Can anyone help me to write that algorithm?

Thank you in advance

Comment: try search for "transpose matrix algorithm" and share us how far u get..

Comment: you can search for Adjacency matrices representation of graph, something like this:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs